# Which Polish political parties are supporting the blockade of their border with Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine, parties, borders, poland

There's [been](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/polish-farmers-suspend-protest-ukraine-border-truckers-stay-2023-12-23/) a partial blockade of Ukraine's borders by Polish truckers and farmers since the beginning of November, punctuated by various short breaks.

> Polish drivers have been blocking several crossings with Ukraine since Nov. 6, demanding the European Union reinstate a system whereby Ukrainian companies need permits to operate in the bloc, and the same for European truckers seeking to enter Ukraine.
>
> They were later joined by farmers who demanded government subsidies for corn and no hikes in taxes.

From earlier [coverage](https://www.politico.eu/article/truck-chaos-poland-border-block-ukraine-kyiv-warsaw-alliance-integration-eu/) on Nov 29:

> More than 3,000 trucks are now stuck at four border crossings; waiting times are as long as three weeks and at least one driver has died while trapped. Protesters are camped out in tents dusted with snow, warming themselves by fires in open barrels, while drivers, dressed in hi-viz vests, stand by their trucks, many of them smoking and looking on at the flashing blue lights of police cars monitoring the situation. [...]
>
> The European Commission issued a blistering criticism on Wednesday of Warsaw's “complete lack of involvement," in ending the crisis.
>
> "The Polish authorities are the ones who are supposed to enforce the law at that border," Transport Commissioner Adina Vălean said in Brussels. "While I support the right of people to protest, the entire EU — not to mention Ukraine, a country currently at war — cannot be taken hostage by blocking our external borders. It’s as simple as that."
>
> [...] Instability in Warsaw is opening the door to activists from Poland’s far-right Confederation party.
>
> “Ukrainians used to carry out 160,000 trucking operations before the war. This year to date it’s been nearly 1 million,” said Rafał Mekler, owner of a trucking company from Międzyrzec Podlaski in eastern Poland.
>
> Mekler isn’t simply a rank-and-file trucker. He's also a Confederation politician who has been heavily involved in organizing the border protests. His Facebook page is rife with criticism of Ukraine, and his party is Poland's most skeptical of the alliance with Kyiv.

(The NYT [reported](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/20/world/europe/blocked-by-polish-truckers-ukraine-turns-to-the-black-sea-to-boost-trade.html) on Dec 20 that the queues had reached 5,000 vehicles.)

Which Polish parties besides (apparently) the  [Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederation_Liberty_and_Independence) support this blockade?

Comment: Confederation is exactly the party, which has organized this blockade, so by excluding it doesnt look, at lest for me, you get an aswer which matches the question. External players are not Polish political parties.

Comment: @cnv: I'm not excluding it. It's not too clear to me though from those reports if the party as a whole supports those.  Googling for Mekler, who doesn't have any Wikipedia pages, isn't too informative even as to his position within Confederation.